# prove there is no tournament with 4 vertices and 4 kings

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone help me prove there is no tournament with 4 vertices and 4 kings.  (Also written as no (4,4) flock)

I have been trying to strategize a starting point for the proof but I cant come up with a solid starting point

Comment: What is a king?

Comment: @bof a king is a chicken that can peck all other chickens by either 1 step or 2 steps

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it possible that every chicken pecks at least two other chickens (in one step)? No, that's not possible. (Why not?)
2. So there is a chicken that pecks just one other chicken. Call that chicken $A$ and call the chicken it pecks $B$.
3. If $A$ is a king, then $B$ must peck the two remaining chickens, call them $C$ and $D$.
4. Either $C$ pecks $D$ or $D$ pecks $C$, let's say $C$ pecks $D$.
5. If $D$ is a king, then $D$ pecks $C$ in two steps. Is that possible?